# dynamicly add A data anchor to url

Tags: jquery

I have a html page with text. In text i have a lot of anchors:

```
<a href="#" data-brand="Ford">Ford</a> 
<a href="#" data-type="Mustang">Mustang</a>.
```

In the end of text i have a links to external sources like:

```
http://example1.com
```

By clicking anchors in text i need add this anchors to external links.

```
http://example1.com/?data-brand=ford&data-type=Mustang
```

Can you help me with it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You first need to write the code yourself and then test it. If it does not work, then we will take a look at the code. The guys in here do not write the codes for people, they help people correct their codes.

Comment: @ManuelCheța Here only correct code? You funny. in my question i doesnt ask wright code to me. i ask help. maybe advise. not create project for me :)

Answer (score 2):

Normally you need to show at least something that you tried yourself, pleas for general recommendations are out of the scope of this website. Nevertheless, I took sort of a personal interest in the task, so here's what I made so far:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $('a[href="#"]').click(function() {
        $.each($(this).data(), function (type, val) {
            $('#external_links').children("a").each(function() {
                var href = $(this).attr('href');
                if (href.indexOf('?') > -1)
                {
                    $(this).attr('href', href+'&data-'+type+'='+val);
                } else {
                    $(this).attr('href', href+'?data-'+type+'='+val);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<span id="external_links">
    <a href="http://example1.com">Test1</a>
    <a href="http://example2.com">Test2</a>
    <a href="http://example3.com">Test3</a>
    <a href="http://example4.com">Test4</a>
</span>
```

The function only edits the anchors contained in the `external_links` container.

Comment: tnx a lot. this is what i looking for, спасибо

Comment: @Andry set the answer as accepted if it helped you. Next time at least include a draft of what you're trying to accomplish.